# Why unshare(CLONE_NEWNET) requires CAP_SYS_ADMIN?

Tags: linux, linux-namespaces

I'm playing with linux namespaces and I've noticed that if a user wants to execute a process in a new network namespace (without using user namespaces) he needs to be root or have the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability.

The [unshare(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unshare) manpage says:

> CLONE_NEWNET (since Linux 2.6.24)
>
> This  flag  has the same effect as the clone(2) CLONE_NEWNET flag.
> Unshare the network namespace, so that the calling process is moved into a new net‐work namespace which is not shared with any previously existing process.  Use of CLONE_NEWNET requires the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability.

So, if I want to execute a pdf reader in a network sandbox I must use user-net-namespaces or some privileged wrapper.

Why?  The new process will be placed in a new network namespace with no interfaces, so it will be isolated from the real network, right?  Which kind of problems/security threats do unprivileged non user network namespaces raise?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a network namespace allows manipulating the execution environment of binaries that have the setuid flag or are otherwise privileged. User namespaces take away this possibility, because a process cannot gain privileges that are not included in the user namespace.

In general, it cannot be known that no security vulnerability is caused by denying a privileged process from accessing the network. Therefore, the kernel assumes that operation is privileged, and it is up to the system policy to decide whether a privileged utility is provided for ordinary users.